# Powershell copy file after a date has passed with file structure

Tags: date, powershell, copy, filepath

I am trying to copy a file off a server and onto another, I want to keep the structure of the file like so C:\folder\folder\file! If the folder is there copy the file into it, if it is not then create the folders and then copy into it! 
I would like it also to filter out the files that are still needed so I want to keep files for 30 days and then move them!

> Blockquote

```
`[int]$Count = 0 
 $filter = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk | ForEach-Object{
 $SearchFolders = Get-Childitem ($_.DeviceID + "\crams") -recurse 
 $FileList = $SearchFolders |
 Where-Object {$_.name -like "Stdout_*" -and $_.lastwritetime -le $filter}  
 [int]$Totalfiles = ($FileList | Measure-object).count 
 write-host "There are a total of $Totalfiles found." 
 echo $FileList
 start-sleep 30 

 [int]
 ForEach ($Item in $FileList) 
 {$Count++
 $File = $Item 
 Write-Host "Now Moving $File" 
 $destination ="C:\StdLogFiles\" 
 $path = test-Path (get-childitem $destination -Exclude "Stdout_*") 

 if ($path -eq $true) { 
   write-Host "Directory Already exists" 
   copy-item $File -destination $destination  
 } 
   elseif ($path -eq $false) { 
        cd $destination 
        mkdir $File 
        copy-Item  $File -destination  $destination 
     }
  }
}`
```

Is what I have so far it has changed a lot due to trying to get it to work but the search works and so does the date part I can not get it to keep the structure of the file!

Okay I took out the bottom part and put in
    `ForEach ($Item in Get-ChildItem $FileList)` 
also tried get-content but path is null
    `{$Count++
     $destination = "C:\StdLogFiles"
     $File = $Item
     Write-Host "Now Moving $File to $destination" 
     Copy-Item -Path $file.fullname -Destination $destination -force}}`

it is copying everything that is in c into that folder but not the files I do not understand what it is doing now! I had it copying the files even wen back to an older version and can't get it to work again! I am going to leave it before I break it more!

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated

Comment: Punctuation is important. If you want people to help you, please try to make your question easy to read. Outside of code I do not see a single period in what you typed.

Answer (score 0):

I think RoboCopy is probably a simpler solution for you to be honest. But, if you insist on using PowerShell you are going to need to setup your destination better if you want to keep your file structure. You also want to leave your filter date as a `[DateTime]` object instead of converting it to a string since what you are comparing it to (lastwritetime) is a `[DateTime]` object. You'll need to do something like:

```
$filter = (Get-Date).AddDays(-15)
$FileList = Get-WMIObject Win32_LogicalDisk | ForEach-Object{
    Get-Childitem ($_.DeviceID + "\crams") -recurse  | Where-Object {$_.name -like "Stdout_*" -and $_.lastwritetime -le $filter} 
} 
$Totalfiles = $FileList.count 

For($i = 1;$i -le $TotalFiles; $i++) 
{
    $File = $FileList[($i-1)]
    Write-Progress -Activity "Backing up old files" -CurrentOperation ("Copying file: " + $file.Name) -Status "$i of $Totalfiles files" -PercentComplete ($i*100/$Totalfiles)
    $Destination = (Split-Path $file.fullname) -replace "^.*?\\crams", "C:\StdLogFiles"
    If(!(Test-Path $Destination)){
        New-Item -Path $Destination -ItemType Directory | Out-Null
    }
    Copy-Item $File -Destination $Destination
}
Write-Progress -Completed
```

That gathers all the files you need to move from all disks. Takes a count of them, and then enters a loop that will cycle as many times as you have files. In the loop is assigns the current item to a variable, then updates a progress bar based on progress. It then parses the destination by replacing the beginning of the file's full path (minus file name) with your target destination of 'C:\StdLogFiles'. So `D:\Crams\HolyPregnantNunsBatman\Stdout04122015.log` becomes `C:\StdLogFiles\HolyPregnantNunsBatman`. Then it tests the path, and if it's not valid it creates it (piped to `out-null` to avoid spam). Then we copy the file to the destination and move on to the next item. After the files are done we close out the progress bar.

Comment: I get an error
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\stdout_20150428134203.log' because it does not exist.
At line:15 char:9
+         Copy-Item $File -Destination $Destination
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\stdout_20150428134203.log:String) [Copy-Item], 
    ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand cmdlet Write-Progress at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
(Type !? for Help.)
Activity:

Comment: When I try to run the script I get the error above. I do not know why it is trying to use the file as the destination. How would I change that or make it not use that as part of the destination and just use the file as an object to copy?  I would use robocopy, but I am unsure how I would! I only want the files that I need, I could use the /IF and /xx options!